# Regex match last three integers and one character before that integers

Tags: awk

I have been trying this for a lot of time,but my search is failing..I have below test data

```
mhie0104:x:104:600:Martinescu Horia:/home/scs/gr911/mhie0104:/bin/bash
mlie0105:x:105:600:Martinescu Laurentiu:/home/scs/gr911/mlie0105:/bin/bash
mmie0106:x:106:600:Martinescu Marius:/home/scs/gr911/mmie0106:/bin/bash
mnie0107:x:107:600:Martinescu Nicolae:/home/scs/gr911/mnie0107:/bin/bash
mpiel110:x:110:600:Malinescu Paul:/home/scs/gr911/mpie110:/bin/bash
```

I am trying to find out users,who has exact three digits at the end ..So below is what i did

```
awk -F: '$1 ~ /*[a-z]//d{3}/'
```

**My understanding of using above regex is  :**
"*" at the begining should match any characters
`[a-z]` it should match any character string  just before digits
Finally three digits

I also tried with below variation

```
awk -F: '$1 ~ /*?//d{3}/'
```

So what i need from above test data is

```
 mpiel110:x:110:600:Malinescu Paul:/home/scs/gr911/mpie110:/bin/bash
```

Comment: You're mixing up different pattern syntaxes. `*` means "any characters in wildcard ("glob") patterns, but in regular expressions it means "zero or more of the previous thing" (the regex for "any characters" is `.*`), and `\d` (not `/d`) means digit only in some versions of regex syntax... but not the one `awk` uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***1st solution:*** If you want to see only last 4 characters of 1st field where 4th last character is NOT digit then you can try following code.

```bash
awk -F':' '$1 ~ /[^0-9][0-9]{3}$/'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

- Simply making field separator as `:` for all the line of Input_file.
- Then checking condition with 1st field `/[^0-9][0-9]{3}$/` if 4 letter from last is anything apart from digit and last 3 are digit then print that line.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you want to check if none of characters(from starting of 1st field except last 3 characters) should contain digit and last 3 characters should be digits then try following code.

```bash
awk -F':' '
substr($1,1,length($1)-3)!~/[0-9]/ && int(substr($1,length($1)-2))~/^[0-9]{3}$/
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

- First thing first making field separator as `:` for this `awk` program.
- using `substr` function of `awk` to get sub string and using `substr($1,1,length($1)-3)!~/[0-9]/` condition I am checking if everything of 1st field apart from last 3 characters is NOT having digit.
- Then checking another condition `int(substr($1,length($1)-2))~/^[0-9]{3}$/` where last 3 characters are of 3 digits.
- If both of the conditions are TRUE then print that line.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use this kind of notation : `\d`

This is perl type regex.

### Solution:

```
$ awk -F: '$1 ~ /[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}$/' file
mpiel110:x:110:600:Malinescu Paul:/home/scs/gr911/mpie110:/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use negative lookbehind in perl

```
$ perl -F: -ne ' print if $F[0]=~/(?<!\d)\d{3}$/ ' gameiswar.txt 
mpiel110:x:110:600:Malinescu Paul:/home/scs/gr911/mpie110:/bin/bash
$
```

Answer (score 3):

For this particular task, `sed` might be used as well:

```
sed '/^[^0-9]*[0-9]\{3\}:/!d' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you can use only digits as the username, but as it is the first field, and the `:` is present as the delimiter.

Here, `([^:]*[^0-9])?` matches optional repetitions of any char except `:` followed by a char other than `0-9`:

```
awk '/^([^:]*[^0-9])?[0-9]{3}:/' file
```

If there has to be a leading char `a-z`

```
awk '/^[^:]*[a-z][0-9]{3}:/' file
```

Output

```
mpiel110:x:110:600:Malinescu Paul:/home/scs/gr911/mpie110:/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mawk '!_<NF' FS='^[^:]*[a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]:'
> ```

— or —

> ```
> gawk '!_<NF' FS='^[^:]*[a-z][0-9]{3}:'
> ```

```
  mpiel110:x:110:600:Malinescu Paul:/home/scs/gr911/mpie110:/bin/bash
```